# Regex to allow only Semi colon(;)

Tags: apex

I have a field which should allow only semi-colon as special character. I can achieve this with below lines,

```
       string Fr_chars = cp.Franchise_GILD_E__c.Trim(); 
       string regex ='[;]';
       Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
       Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(Fr_chars);
       boolean regexfind =  regexMatcher.find();
       if(!(regexFind))
        {
         system.debug('Error') }
```

This shows error correctly for below value, `ANF.HIV` . But if the value is `AU;NZ.IN` its not showing. Is there a way to check if the field contains any special charecters other than `;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this regex pattern

```
string regex ='[^A-Za-z0-9;]';
//this will ok only A-Z "standard" letters, "standard" digits and Semi colon.
```

Here is full code sample for you

```
string regex ='[^A-Za-z0-9;]';
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher('AU;NZ;NZ');
boolean regexfind =  regexMatcher.find();
if((regexFind))
{
    system.debug('Error'); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression character class subtraction to match all punctuation minus one character. It looks like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('[\\p{Punct}&&[^;]]');
Boolean regexfind = p.matcher(cp.Franchise_GILD_E__c).find();
```

The `&&[^...]` means "and not these characters." This code allows all alpha-numeric characters, even those with accents, umlauts, etc.